# Instantiate Facebook adaccount object with post data

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, api

I am trying to create a new obect of adaccount with the Facebook marketing API with post data. When I hard code the act_{number} it works fine but when I try to insert the post data variable it fails. Here is my code. Thanks for any insight!

```
<?php
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
 if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
 }

$id = $_POST['actid'];

define('VENDOR_DIR', '/'); // Path to the Vendor directory 
$loader = include 'vendor/autoload.php';

use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdSetFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\UserFields;

if(isset($_SESSION['fb_access_token'])) {

// Initialize a new Session and instanciate an Api object
Api::init('{appinfo}', '{appinfo}', $_SESSION['fb_access_token']);

// The Api object is now available trough singleton
$api = Api::instance();

$account = new AdAccount($id);

$adsets = $account->getAdSets(array(
  AdSetFields::NAME,
));



header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('id'=>$id));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The post data had weird whitespace added. All I needed to do was trim the variable.